# How to get the maximum http request length time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, httprequest

In my asp.net/c# website, I make a request that takes like a minute, and sometimes it goes into an error saying the request timed out, and I can't catch it. But I thought of a work around.

I could get the maximum time as a value, then while doing the loop, I can time it, and if it goes past the max amount of time minus 4 seconds, then stop the loop.

But how can I get the maximum time (from web.config file)? Is there a variable I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Explain your problem, not your solution. Why stop four seconds before timeout? What if the request would have succeeded three seconds before timeout? Why can't you catch the timeout? Who is throwing the timeout error? Where are you trying to catch it? Can't you start the long-running request run on the background so the request will return immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think you may check the HttpServerUtility.ScriptTimeout property - it reflects the web.config value for the executionTimeout attribute on httpRuntime element.

MSDN entry on this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: in the web.config file the tag is `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />`, but using this i get 110...?

Comment: maxRequestLength is the size in bytes, not a timeout in milliseconds. That would be the executionTimeout element.

Comment: but in the webconfig file, the only values for any executionTimeout attribute is 3600, which is for specific pages. So if this attribute is not defined is there some default value?

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, yes - and I will quote: 'The ExecutionTimeout property indicates the maximum number of seconds a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET. The default is 110 seconds.'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you to get the value you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Another, easier way is to read the config directly:

```
HttpRuntimeSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as HttpRuntimeSection;

lblDebug.Text = section.MaxRequestLength.ToString();
```

Comment: How can I get the current HttpWebRequest? It needs an object reference.

Comment: You can create a new one, as shown in the example on the MSDN page